# Average sum of seria

Tags: probability, summation, average

I need some help with the next question in probability:

In the range {1,2,...,100}, someone picks randomly 15 different numbers, with the same probability for each number.

1. What is the average sum of the 15 numbers (no duplicates are allowed)?
2. Assume that the probability of choosing even number is 3 times bigger than choosing odd number. What will be the average sum now?

Comment: average sum means expected value of the sum?

Comment: Yes, it is the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . $\frac{15}{100}=\frac{3}{20}$ is the probability for each number to be picked. Hence, the expected value of the sum is

$1\cdot \frac{3}{20}+2\cdot \frac{3}{20}+\cdots + 100\cdot \frac{3}{20}= \frac{3}{20} \cdot (1+2+\cdots 100)=757.5$

2 . Let $p$ be the probability for an odd number to be picked. Then the probability for an even number to be picked is $4p$. (There might be confusion here. Mathematically, $3$ times bigger than means $4$ times as big as, at least to my understanding. But in daily life, people who say $3$ times bigger than usually mean $3$ times as big as.) There are $50$ even numbers and $50$ odd numbers. So, $p \cdot 50 + 4p \cdot 50=15$. We obtain $p=\frac{3}{50}, 4p=\frac{12}{50}$. Therefore, the expected value of the sum is

$1\cdot \frac{3}{50} + 3\cdot \frac{3}{50}+\cdots + 99\cdot \frac{3}{50}+2\cdot \frac{12}{50} +4\cdot \frac{12}{50}+\cdots+100\cdot\frac{12}{50}$
$=\frac{3}{50}\cdot(1+3+\cdots99)+\frac{12}{50}\cdot(2+4+\cdots+100)$

Comment: I meant 3 times bigger as 3p. Is your ansewr based on the fact that number couldn't be chosen twice?